# Is there any "babytype"-like aplication on ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, training

Please, let me know what are the best keyboard type trainers for children on Ubuntu? I was asked to use babytype but this app is for Windows OS but I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: You should be able to run that app in Wine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Tux Typing](https://tux4kids.alioth.debian.org/tuxtype/screens.php) or [Klavaro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/klavaro/) (which is more advanced and maybe not for babies).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'd like type trainer as a game, for children it would be more interesting.